# CCCallFunc: Selector not being called in inherited class

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to schedule selectors with CCCallFunc but the selector isn't getting called.

This works:

```
[self launchCreature];
```

This does not:

```
id launchCreatureAction = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(launchCreature)];
[self runAction:launchCreatureAction];
```

launchCreature is defined in the parent class, and the CCCallFunc works when used in the parent class. Nothing is showing up in the debugger when I run the action; it just doesn't run the code. (It never hits the breakpoint I have defined at the first line of launchCreature.)

Am I missing about something about how to use CCCallFunc, or how self works in subclasses?

**Edit**: I misremembered how my code is set up. launchCreature and the code above are BOTH defined in the parent class. <strike>The difference between working and not working is that it worked in an instance of the parent class, but doesn't work in an instance of the subclass.</strike> This no longer seems to work in the parent class either. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: if 'self' is not running (has been added as a child to a running node), actions would not run.

Comment: Thanks. In this case, self is a child of a CCLayer, which is a child of a CCScene, which has been loaded using the code `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[Level1Scene node]]`. How can I tell whether or not that counts as a running node?

Comment: Did a little more digging. I added an onEnter method to the class, and it is getting called. That means it's running, right?

Comment: yes ... dont forget to [super onEnter].

Comment: To verify further, I ran `[self isRunning]` right before the `[self runAction:launchCreatureAction];` line, and it returns TRUE. So the node is definitely running. But it's just not running the CCAction.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. You could try making a call to [super launchCreature] in [self launchCreature] in the subclass and see if the break point is being hit.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not sure what you mean. Are you saying replace [self launchCreature] with [super launchCreature] in the code above, or override the launchCreature method in the subclass, and have the first line of the new method be [super launchCreature]?

Comment: sorry for not being clear. I meant overriding the launchCreature method in the subclass and call [super launchCreature] in the first line.

Comment: Ah, OK. No worries; thanks for the suggestion. I just tried that and found that not even the subclass method is getting called. At least that eliminates something about class inheritance being the problem.